# Missing end , Unable to perform cross join mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to do a cross join between two Select statements in mysql.
However, I get an error saying missing end.
However, there is no need of an end statement there

Here is the code

```
SELECT starts_at, (@row := @row + 1) + start_health_post_id as health_post_id
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL start_time MINUTE) AS starts_at
    FROM days
    CROSS JOIN times
) 
slots, (SELECT @row := -1)r
ORDER BY starts_at;

cross join 

Select practices.id as practice_id, providers.id as provider_id, 
        practice_locations.id as practice_location_id
from practices 
Inner Join  providers on practices.health_post_id = providers.health_post_id

Inner join practice_locations on practices.health_post_id =     

practice_locations.health_post_id;
```

Comment: is that `;` intended just before the second CROSS JOIN?

Comment: yes., It is just before the cross join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MySQL Manual:

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents
>   (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not
>   equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used
>   otherwise.

I think you need to enclose both queries in `( )`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT starts_at, (@row := @row + 1) + start_health_post_id as health_post_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL start_time MINUTE) AS starts_at
        FROM days
        CROSS JOIN times
    ) 
    slots, (SELECT @row := -1) r
    ORDER BY starts_at
  ) as t1
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    Select practices.id as practice_id, providers.id as provider_id, 
            practice_locations.id as practice_location_id
    from practices 
    Inner Join  providers on practices.health_post_id = providers.health_post_id

    Inner join practice_locations on practices.health_post_id =     

    practice_locations.health_post_id
  ) as t2
  ON t1.`t1_field` =  t2.`t2_field` -- change it as you need;
```